# Pointer to Pointer in Julia

Tags: pointers, julia

I need to do allocate memory in a ccallable function determine_string(...) in Julia, see code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

module ProductionCode
    import Printf

    Base.@ccallable function determine_string(msg_p_p::Ptr{Ptr{Cchar}})::Nothing
        println("determine_string(): msg_p_p ", msg_p_p)

        json_string::String = join([Printf.@sprintf("%15.7f", rand()) for i in 1:10])
        size_for_malloc::Csize_t = 1 + length(json_string)

        msg_p_p = @ccall malloc(size_for_malloc::Csize_t)::Ptr{Nothing}
        println("determine_string(): msg_p_p ", msg_p_p)

        println("determine_string(): json_string ", json_string)

        @ccall memcpy(msg_p_p::Ptr{Ptr{Cchar}}, json_string::Ptr{Cchar}, size_for_malloc::Csize_t)::Cvoid

        return nothing
    end

end # ProductionCode

function test()::Nothing
    msg_p::Ptr{Cchar} = C_NULL
    msg_p_p = <pointer to msg_p>

    println("test(): msg_p ", msg_p)
    ProductionCode.determine_string(msg_p_p)
    println("test(): msg_p ", msg_p)

    @ccall printf("printf: %s\n"::Ptr{Cchar}, msg_p::Ptr{Cchar})::Cint

    julia_string::String = Base.unsafe_string(Base.convert(Ptr{Cchar}, msg_p))

    @ccall free(msg_p::Ptr{Cchar})::Cvoid
    msg_p = C_NULL

    return nothing
end

test()
```

Here determine_string(...) represents a function that determines a variable length string that has to be sent to the caller in C. The caller will use the string and free the memory. For unit test purposes, determine_string(...) has to be callable from Julia too.

Questions:

- How to I get the pointer to pointer?
- How do I do the malloc? How do I do the memcpy?